# Line Breaks when reading excel file on html

Tags: excel, meteor, line-breaks

I am having problems introducing break lines for my bullet points. 
I am using a meteorjs application that is hosted on heroku, and using readxlsx.

I am reading entries from an excel file, but it is being read as one whole text block, and I have tried many ways to introduce line breaks such as including `<br>` inside the text, but to no avail. Currently, the bullet points are symbols added in excel.

Would greatly appreciate any help. Thank you.

Website can be accessed at http://zera.herokuapp.com/drugdetail/Paracetamol

I have included screenshots of the excel sheet

**`Screenshot of Excel`**
[image: Excel Screenshot]

**`Screenshot of Website`**
As you can see, the bullet points look very off.
[image: Website Screenshot]

**`Screenshot of Web Developer Tools`**

[image: Web developer tools (when inspecting)]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved with adding css:

white-space:pre-line;
margin-top:-20px;